# Reprecussions of deactivating or force activating SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature

Tags: 2013, feature-activation

I am receiving an error when I try to activate the SharePoint Server Publishing feature on a sub-site:

> Content type
>   '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39'
>   not found in web 'SubSiteURL'.

It's my understanding that this is related to the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature (which is activated for this site collection), and that I should deactivate and then reactivate that feature at the site collection. After which, I should be able to activate the SharePoint Server Publishing feature for subsites.

This particular site collection has many subsites, which have quite a bit of custom content. I've read that the Infrastructure feature creates a few different content types, such as Page. Will deactivating or force activating with stsadm destroy any of the data/custom content in the subsites?

Comment: Have you found out if there is any impact when deactivating and reactivating the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on existing content?

Comment: @TempaC - I was able to deactivate and reactivate these features without any problems. I ended up cloning (backup and restore elsewhere) the site collection and trying there before performing the procedure on the production site collection. Everything worked perfectly, in my scenario.